# MongoDB Aggregation: "Populate" (resolve) Ref in Nested Array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

### Background

I have a collection `Items` with documents such as

```
{
  "_id": "5d9e3a5ced27230f68032e21",
  ... more fields
  "foos": [
    {
      "_id": "5d9e3a5ced27230f68032e25",
      ... more fields
      "bars": [
        "5d9dab461bbb4db66db41f93"
      ],
    },
    {
      "id": "5d9e3a5ced27230f68032e24",
      ... more fields
      "bars": [
        "5d9dab461bbb4db66db41f93",
        "5d9e3a23ed27230f68032e1a"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

with `bars` referring to another collection `Bars`.

### Goal

I'd like to get a list of all documents (with all their fields) in `Items`, but with `bars` resolved to the document in `Bars`.

### Small Catch

I want to be able to create a generic function to which I simply pass the path to resolve (e.g. `foos.bars`) and the collection from which to resolve (`Bars`) so that I can use it with different collections and arbitrary levels of nesting.

### Initial Approach

I've found a rather complicated way to do this for my example, but before I generalize it, I'd like to know whether there really isn't a simpler way. Input is highly appreciated!

Here's what I've got:

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$foos", 
      "includeArrayIndex": "foos_index"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$foos.bars"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Bars", 
      "localField": "foos.bars", 
      "foreignField": "_id", 
      "as": "foos.bars"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$foos.bars"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "id": "$_id", 
        "foo_index": "$foos_index"
      }, 
      "foos": {
        "$first": "$foos"
      }, 
      "bars": {
        "$push": "$foos.bars"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "foos": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$foos",
          {
            "bars": "$bars"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.id", 
      "foos": {
        "$push": "$foos"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Items", 
      "localField": "_id", 
      "foreignField": "_id", 
      "as": "original_doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$original_doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$original_doc",
          {
            "foos": "$foos"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

### Update: First Iteration

I've realized I don't need the "leaf" level unwound, so I've now got a simplified version (but for deeper nesting, I'll still need what I had before, right?):

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$foos", 
      "includeArrayIndex": "foos_index"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Bars", 
      "localField": "foos.bars", 
      "foreignField": "_id", 
      "as": "foos.bars"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id", 
      "foos": {
        "$push": "$foos"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Items", 
      "localField": "_id", 
      "foreignField": "_id", 
      "as": "original_doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$original_doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$original_doc",
          {
            "foos": "$foos"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone still finds something better, but until then, if someone comes across this, the following seems reasonable to me by now:

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$foos", 
      "includeArrayIndex": "foos_index"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Bars", 
      "localField": "foos.bars", 
      "foreignField": "_id", 
      "as": "foos.bars"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "savepoint": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      },
      "foos": {
        "$push": "$foos"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$savepoint",
          {
            "foos": "$foos"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```